# Script setup - how to use props in computed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```html
<script setup>
import { defineProps, computed } from '@vue/runtime-core'

defineProps({
  foo: Array,
})

const length = computed(() => {
  return foo.length         // foo is not defined
})
</script>
```

In this block which is quite self-explained, when I try to reach props variable in computed, an error throws like 'foo is not defined'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`defineProps` returns a reference to the given props, from which you could access `foo` in `computed`:

```html
<script setup>
import { defineProps, computed } from 'vue'
        
const myProps = defineProps({
  foo: Array,
})

const length = computed(() => {
  return myProps.foo.length
})          
</script>
```

[demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Never seen such a didactic explanation with those pretty hands. Clap clap!

Comment: I was looking for an answer in the official Vue.js 3 docs for an hour already. You saved me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Deconstructing the prop definition gets clear of some boilerplate code, and gives you direct access to them throughout the script :)

```
import { computed } from 'vue'
//since I last tested, don't need to import defineProps

const { foo } = defineProps({ 
  foo: Array,
})

const length = computed(() => {
  return foo.length
})          
</script>
```